# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] not working

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery-mobile

Im sorry if this kind of question has been asked before. but i spent much time searching for but I could not find the solution. so i'm posting here..

Problem:
I'm trying to post the values onto the same page(working with Jquery mobile UI). so I'm using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in action for my form in the page. Please check the spelling for action(working for actoin but not for action)

when i'm using this its posting in the same page and i'm happy

```
<form method="POST" actoin="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Please check the spelling for action

but,
when I'm using this `<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">`

Its pointing to index.php of my application.

can anyone please tell me..why its happening like this..please note that I know that its typo..

Thanks,

Comment: This question will be closed as too localized shortly

Comment: You spelled `action` wrong: `actoin`

Comment: yes..thats the problem..its working for actoin but not for action..pls check my spellings

Comment: im sorry but how is this working for `actoin`?

Comment: The only reason that actoin appears to work is because it's an invalid attribute, so it's ignored. Therefore, it's being interpreted as `<form method="post">`

Comment: As an aside, if you want to use action, try echoing `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: View html source, you will see what goes under the hood

Comment: Thanks chris and silent boy...@chriz as chris told..its ignoring actoin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns the name of script. You probably mean `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. It is working with `actoin` because most of browsers will submit it to the same page when there is no `action` attribute.

Comment: brilliant..Thanks friend.. its working with it $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: in case of the current page is index.php?q=123, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returned 'index.php', while $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] equals to 'index.php?q=123'. So be careful.

Answer (score 2):

action not actoin , and you can simply write

```
 <form method="post">
```

without action and it will post values on the same page

Comment: can you please tell me how to write without action??

Comment: For a valid markup, its not recommend to have a form without action attribute. W3C set it as required attr -> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html just saying..

Comment: @sofl - Good point; it would depend if he's using HTML4.01 or HTML5 (it appears to be optional in HTML5...http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)

Comment: thanks Jock.. its working without action too :).. thanks for your time

Comment: @ChrisForrence Even if its optional in HTML5, I think that ancient browser treat the HTML5 doctype as HTML4.01 (default fallback)