# Redirect on a UNIX server when posting a form

Tags: php, forms, unix, redirect

So I finally decided to get an online server so I can share my website that I worked really hard on to the world. But there has been some growing pains. I have never been education on internet server management, so I thought that if it worked on my WAMP server then it would work on any server. So I chose ipage thinking that it would work, and it turned out to be a UNIX server.

There has been this trend on my website where use an AJAX/Jquery event to bring forth a form from another view and whenever I submit a it, and it will go to the original form page. It will execute the query and go through alright, but you have to hit the back button and that is just bad for the user experience. But on my local WAMP server, it works out perfectly.

Let me give you sort of a visual of the code:

The form:

```
<div id='addCard'>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>' method='post'>
<label> Question </label><br><input type='text' name='question' size='30'>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($_POST['question'])) {
        echo "<mark> You must have a question! </mark>";
        $valid = false;
    }
}

?>
<br>
<label> Answer </label><br><input type='text' name='answer' size='30'>
<br>
<label> Extra Information </label><br><input type='text' name='information' size='30' height='100'rows='80' cols='90'>
<br>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['answer'])) {
        echo "<mark> You must have an answer! </mark>";
        $valid = false;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if ($valid) {
        require_once '../Models/classes.php';
        $new_card = new Cards($_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['answer'],
            $_POST['information']);
        $new_card->card_insert($_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['question'], $_POST['answer'],
            $_POST['information']);
    }
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Add Card">
<input type="reset" value="Reset Fields">

</form>
</div>
```

jQuery function used to call forth the form:

```
    $('#addCard').click(function() {
        $('.bar').empty();
        $('.bar').load('add_card.php #addCard');
    });
```

The actual function to put the card into the database:

```
public function card_insert($user_id, $question, $answer, $information){
    $card_insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO Cards(user_id, question, answer, information) VALUES('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_id), mysql_real_escape_string($question), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($answer), mysql_real_escape_string($information));
    $result = mysql_query($card_insert) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result) {

        header("Location: my_cards.php");
    }

}
```

What do you think needs to be changed? Is it a header function I need to add in? I'm using an absolute link and it still goes to that view.

If you wish to try it out for yourself, then try it at: http://www.wonderpenguin.com/Study_Penguin/index.php

If you want to see the folder structure, then check out my github page:
https://github.com/Lalien/Study_Penguin

Comment: In many cases - specifically in your case - there shouldn't be a difference by the operating system.

Comment: @SteAp, that's what I thought, but there were a lot of things plaguing me like everything being case-sensitive and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have different output buffer sizes on the machines. Anyway, `header` can only be set as long as no output has been send to the client.

The function `card_insert` tries to set a location header but there's a lot of HTML code which has been implicitly printed to the client already. Try to change the order and have HTML code always after `header(...)`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is OS independent and scripting language so it will not be problem where you have writen code either wamp or mac or hosted on Linux

Cross check php_self function ?

[See example below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574673/serverphp-self-not-working)