# How Do I Make My PHP Code Stop Displaying Object Not Found?

Tags: php

When I hit the Submit button, I got this instead:
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404.

I've gone through the entire code and I can't seem to spot the bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--super global variables = $_POST & $_SESSION -->
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label>User Name: </label><input type="text" name="username" required><br><br>
    <label>Secret Word: </label><input type="text" name="secret_word" required><br><br>
    <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required><br><br>
    <label>Age: </label><input type="number" name="age" required><br><br>
    <label>Full Name: </label><input type="text" name="fullname" required><br><br>
    <label>Address: </label><input type="text" name="address" required><br><br>
    <label>Costumer Complaint: </label><input type="text" name="cost_comp" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>



<?php 
//Form validation and sanitization
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $raw_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $raw_secret_word = trim($_POST["raw_secret_word"]);
    $raw_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $raw_age = trim($_POST["age"]);
    $raw_fullname = trim($_POST["raw_fullname"]);
    $raw_address = $_POST["raw_address"];
    $raw_cost_comp = $_POST["raw_cost_comp"];

    $clean_username = filter_var($raw_username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $clean_secret_word = filter_var($raw_secret_word, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $clean_email = filter_var($raw_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $clean_age = filter_var($raw_age, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $clean_fullname = filter_var($raw_fullname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    function processCustomerQueries($clean_username, $clean_secret_word,
     $clean_email, $clean_age, $clean_fullname, $raw_address, $raw_cost_comp) {

    if ($clean_username && $clean_secret_word && $clean_email && $clean_age 
        && $clean_fullname && $raw_address && $raw_cost_comp) {

        echo "Hello Dear " . $clean_username . "<br>";
             "Secret Word: " . $clean_secret_word . "<br>";
             "Email: " . $clean_email . "<br>";
             "Age: " . $clean_age . "<br>";
             "Full Name: " . $clean_fullname . "<br>";
             "Full Address: " . $raw_address . "<br>";
             "Full Address: " . $raw_cost_comp . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Please fill the fields above.";
    }
 }

}

echo processCustomerQueries($clean_username, $clean_secret_word,
$clean_email, $clean_age, $clean_fullname, $raw_address, $raw_cost_comp);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574673/serverphp-self-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The error looks to be with how you are getting back to the action in the form, try using a blank action,

```
<!--super global variables = $_POST & $_SESSION -->
<form method="POST" action="">
    <label>User Name: </label><input type="text" name="username" required><br><br>
    <label>Secret Word: </label><input type="text" name="secret_word" required><br><br>
    <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required><br><br>
    <label>Age: </label><input type="number" name="age" required><br><br>
    <label>Full Name: </label><input type="text" name="fullname" required><br><br>
    <label>Address: </label><input type="text" name="address" required><br><br>
    <label>Costumer Complaint: </label><input type="text" name="cost_comp" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```